# KeyPerFileConfigurationSource doesn't have an option to set directory path and ignore condition at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker-secrets

I am using **.NET Core 3.1** and Docker secrets to store sensitive configuration data. I am using `AddKeyPerFile` extension method to tell .NET Core to load key-value pairs from files on file system. I want to set `directoryPath` where these files are located and `IgnoreCondition` to ignore specific files. However, `KeyPerFileConfigurationBuilderExtensions` only contains the following two methods:

```cs
public static IConfigurationBuilder AddKeyPerFile(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, Action<KeyPerFileConfigurationSource> configureSource);
public static IConfigurationBuilder AddKeyPerFile(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, string directoryPath, bool optional);
```

... and `KeyPerFileConfigurationSource` contains the following properties:

```cs
public IFileProvider FileProvider { get; set; }
public Func<string, bool> IgnoreCondition { get; set; }
public string IgnorePrefix { get; set; }
public bool Optional { get; set; }
```

This is the code that I have currently:

```cs
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
// I want to set 'IgnoreCondition' as well
cb.AddKeyPerFile(directoryPath: "/abc123", optional: true);
```

How can I set both `directoryPath` **AND** `IgnoreCondition`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. You should use `PhysicalFileProvider` like so:

```cs
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddKeyPerFile(x =>
    {
        x.FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("/abc123");
        x.Optional = true;
        x.IgnoreCondition = fileName => !fileName.StartsWith("MyApp_");
    });
```